# How to check whether pciutils are installed in ubuntu or not?

Tags: 12.04, server

I have to implement one problem.
which I have done in redhat to check pciutils using 
`rpm -q pciutils` command. But it's failing for ubuntu as rpm command not found.

My question, Is there any generic command to check which pciutils versions are installed or even it's installed or not for Ubuntu of any version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Type in command line `apt-cache policy pciutils` or `dpkg -l | grep pciutils`.

If the package is installed, you'd see an output like this:

[image]

On the other hand, if the package is not installed, the output would be something like:

[image]

Comment: thnks ...... :)